# role="presentation" or aria-hidden="true" for decorative images?

Tags: html, image, accessibility

Which is semantically better, `alt=""`, `role="presentation"`, CSS bg image or `aria-hidden="true"` for hiding decorative images from assistive technologies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing is to use blank `alt` text.

```
<img src="squiggle.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="" />
```

> Using null alt text and no title attribute on img elements for images that AT (Assistive Technology) should ignore.
>
> <sup>[- source](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html)</sup>

Comment: And by "blank", you mean a null alt text (empty string), as quoted in the source.  I just wanted to point that out in case someone saw "blank" and thought hex character 0x32 and used `" "`.  However, equally good to `alt=""` is having a background image in CSS.  Then you don't have to work about the `<img>` tag or `alt` attribute at all.

Answer (score 1):

semantically, the right answer is aria-hidden=true. WCAG 1.1.1 indicate all images must have an alt text, purely decorative images are not a exception, but text alternative must be void, alt="", theoretically this must to be enough but certain assistive technologies still can reach the image and label it as image, so It'll not be hidden anymore.
Any element you want hidden to assistive tech must be aria-hidden and of course, semantically has more sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what assistive technologies will recognise and label it as an `img` as it seems [across the board it's ignored as expected](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/img-null-alt/) with an empty alt.